# Marketo - REST API datetime field is wrong

Tags: marketo

I sent the following string to Marketo REST API to be set as the value of a `datetime` field:

`"2010-05-07T15:41:32"`

But Marketo displays it as:

`May 6, 2010 8:00 PM`

Is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always a bit tricky to deal with `DateTime` properly.

Most probably there are two, but related issues here:

- The format of the *datetime* string you are using is not exactly the format that Marketo expects.
- You are living in a timezone that is different to the internal timezone Marketo uses.

Luckily, you can easily overcome this issue.
The exact format for the *datetime* string should follow the ISO 8601 standard, as it is described in the [Field Types](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/lead-database/fields/field-types/) section of the documentation. An important part of that specification is the timezone offset, which follows the “normal” *datetime* part as the difference to Greenwich time in the form of `±hh:mm`. So, depending on your timezone, your date string should look like somthing like this: `2017-05-08T08:08:08+02:00`. (Where `+02:00` is for Central Europe.)

In case you are using PHP, the easiest way to have this format is by using the [`c`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) full Date/Time format, like so:

```php
$date = new DateTime('2010-05-07 15:41:32', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Budapest'));
$dateString = $date->format('c');

var_dump($dateString);
// outputs: '2017-05-08T08:08:08+02:00'
```